# I am doing two email field match validation by jquery in codeigniter. Data passing through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is external js(validation.js) doing two email field match validation

```
$(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var confirmEmail = $("#emailconf").val();
            if (email != confirmEmail) {
                alert("Passwords do not match.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
```

this is HTML view(myform.php) my query executing but not working problem is that how i execute my jquery my email field validation not working

Iam passing data through AJAX.This is HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<html>
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
//header("location: http://localhost/ci/Form/user_login_process");
}
?>
<head> 

<title>Registration</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets\css\style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/validation.js')?>"></script>




</head>

<body style="background-color:rgb(90,90,90);color:white  " >
<form id="reg_form"  class="form-horizontal"  >

<div class="container-fluid">



<div class="col-sm-2"></div>


<div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:white; margin-top: 120px; border-radius:20px;">



<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:955px; margin-top:-200px;" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/ci/form/fetch'">Dash Board</button>

<h2><legend style="color:#678;"><center>Enter Your Details Here</center><span class="req" >required *</span></legend></h2>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="control-label col-sm-2" ><span class="req">*</span>Username</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name"/>
</div>
<span class="error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
</div>
</div>






<div class="form-group">
<label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">*</span>Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="password"  name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Password"/>
</div>
<span class="error"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="passconf" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">*</span>ConfirmPassword</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="password"  name="passconf" id="passconf" class="form-control"  placeholder="Confirm Users Password"/>
</div>
<span class="error"<?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">* </span>Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com"/>
</div>
<span class="error"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?><span>
</div>
</div>
</br>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="emailconf" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">* </span>ConfirmEmail</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="emailconf" id="emailconf" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com"/>
</div>
<span class="error"><?php echo form_error('emailconf'); ?><span>
</div>
</div>




</br>

</br>
<div class="form-group row"> 

<div class="col-md-2"> </div>      
<div class=" col-sm-8" style="text-align: center;">
<button type="button" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"  style="margin-left: 16px;" >Submit</button>
<button type="reset"  id="reset" name="reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>



<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>form/login" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-2"> </div> 
</div>
</form>







<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){  

    $.ajax({
       url:"<?php echo site_url('form/new_user_registration') ?>",
       type: 'POST',
       data: $("#reg_form").serialize(),


       success: function(res){


           alert("Data inserted successfully ?");
           $("#reg_form").html(res);
           $('#username').val('');
           $('#password').val('');
           $('#passconf').val('');
           $('#email').val('');
           $('#emailconf').val('');


       },

       error: function(){
           alert("Fail")
       }
   });
   return false;
  });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(){
   $("select").trigger("change");
});
</script>
```

Comment: but My jquery validation is not working... query executing but not working. pls give me solution.  thnks in advance . validation doing for two email fields match.

Answer (score -1):

Add you'r first function before the `$.ajax` and if email and confirmation email dont match, do a `event.preventDefault()` This will look like this :

```
    $(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var confirmEmail = $("#emailconf").val();
        if (email != confirmEmail) {
            alert("Passwords do not match.");
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            do ajax code here
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: can u do edit my code , in where i insert my AJAX. i did but no result.

Comment: Data is not submitting after click on the submit button.

Comment: #Sebastien Napo internal jquery is working, but when i using external jquery it is not working and data not submitting.

Comment: working internal js but in the external js email validation doing work but data not passing through ajax. pls solve my problem